# Get rectangle bounds from string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I want to save bounds of my window in registry, for that I use code:

```
dialogView.Save("WindowPosition", this.DesktopBounds.ToString());
```

dialogView is the path where i want to save them. it saves everything ok
example:

```
{X=54,Y=153,Width=723,Height=555}
```

but  how is the best way to get them, because the type which I can get from registry
can be string
example:

```
dialogView.Load("WindowPosition",string.Empty,out position);
```

but how to convert string to rectangle to init setting to window I don't know? can someone suggest something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try a [RectangeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangleconverter.aspx):

```
RectangleConverter r = new RectangleConverter();

var rectangleAsString= r.ConvertToString(this.DesktopBounds);

var rectangle = (Rectangle)r.ConvertFromString(rectangleAsString);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Regex pattern:

```
{X=(\d+),\s*Y=(\d+),\s*Width=(\d+),Height=(\d+)}
```

See the **demo** [here](http://rubular.com/r/eCVoSYnu0A).

```
Match groups:
1.  54
2.  153
3.  723
4.  555
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var matches = Regex.Match("{X=54,Y=153,Width=723,Height=555}",
                           @"\D*(\d+)\D*(\d+)\D*(\d+)\D*(\d+)");

var rect = new Rectangle(int.Parse(matches.Groups[1].Value),
                         int.Parse(matches.Groups[2].Value),
                         int.Parse(matches.Groups[3].Value),
                         int.Parse(matches.Groups[4].Value));
```